# emacs unable to open PDF files in Preview: "permission denied"

Tags: osx, pdf, helm-bibtex

This is not an emacs problem so far as I'm aware, and only occurred after I upgraded from macOS Catalina 10.15.? to 10.15.7. Any help resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

I'm using helm-bibtex to manage my references. Previously, everything was working seamlessly. After the upgrade above (which my computer did without my consent!), I have been getting the following error when I try to open most of my PDF files in Preview via helm-bibtex:

> The file “file.pdf” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
>
> To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

Obviously, the permissions on the PDF file are totally okay (`rw-r--r--`), so this message is completely unhelpful. I have given emacs and `/usr/bin/ruby` Full Disk Access as instructed elsewhere on emacs.SE, and to no avail. I have also tried toggling permissions of my PDFs using `chmod 644 *.pdf` (and even `chmod 755`).

I've looked through other posts on emacs.SE with similar issues, but the issue is never quite the same as this one, and the proposed solutions I've found so far have not fixed the problem.

Comment: Who produces that error message? It looks like a Mac program does it (does anything in Emacs refer to the "Finder"?). If you can find that out, you can try it from the command line and leave Emacs out of the equation.

Comment: Does this happen only when you try to open the PDFs through emacs, or does it happen no matter how you try to open them?

Comment: Indeed, it's a MacOS/Preview issue. [This post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4892480?answerId=21527875022#21527875022) resolved it.

Comment: Update: that post did not resolve it, after all, but [this one did](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453702/open-myfile-pdf-raises-no-permission-error/453773#453773).